# Extra digits in formatting output in c programming

Tags: c, output

```
float y=98.7654;
printf("%f\n", y);
```

This is giving the output as `98.765404`.
I cannot understand how the output ends with 04, can anybody please explain it?

Comment: In C, `98.7654` is a double and the line `float y = 98.7654;` converts the double to float. Try either `float y = 98.7654f;` or `double y = 98.7654;`.

Comment: @ssd: `float y = 98.7654f;` will have the same result as `float y = 98.7654;`.